# COLLADA DOM open() function returning null because of "topMeta"

Tags: file-io, collada

Im trying to open a [.dae](http://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/DOM_guide%3a_Importing_documents) file.

But when I try to open the document, it is null because something called "topMeta" is null. I don't know how to set topMeta properly.

This is the code

```
DAE dae;

daeElement *root = dae.open("simple.dae");
```

Comment: I would suggest switching to OpenCOLLADA instead. COLLADA DOM is no longer maintained.

Comment: But I don't want to use maya or 3dmax,so I must use collada dom,but still thank you.

Comment: OpenCOLLADA is an independent library. You don't have to use maya or 3dsmax to use it.